# How to split Download-URL with slashes and/or backslashes into URL and Filename

Tags: url, batch-file, split, filenames

how can i split (with a **batch script**) Download-URLs like

```
[with slash]
a) http://www.someone.com/download/files/filename.exe
b) http://www.someone other.com/some files/filename 1.exe  (with spaces !)

[with backslash]
c) http:\\www.someone.com\download\files\filename.exe
d) http:\\www.someone other.com\some files\filename 1.exe  (with spaces !)

[mixed slash and backslash]
e) http:\\www.someone.com/download\files/filename.exe
f) http://www.someone other.com\some files/filename 1.exe  (with spaces !)

and all of the above when there is no HTTP part (starting with "www.")
```

into the (Base-)URL part and the filename part.

One batch script for all variations (and for more than one variable - in a Loop) would be nice :-)

Something like:

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
For %%G in (var1, var2, var3) do (
 set /A COUNT+=1

 ... routine to split "var1", "var2" and "var3" into temporary variables BASEURL and FILENAME

 set Folder!COUNT!=%BASEURL%
 set Name!COUNT!=%FILENAME%
)

Output:
For /L %%A in (1,1,3) do (
 echo URL: !Folder%%A! --- FIILENAME: !Name%%A!
)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET download=https://www.someone.com/download/files/filename.exe&CALL :splitme
SET download=https://www.someone other.com/some files/filename 1.exe&CALL :splitme
SET download=https:\\www.someone.com\download\files\filename.exe&CALL :splitme
SET download=https:\\www.someone other.com\some files\filename 1.exe&CALL :splitme
SET download=https:\\www.someone.com/download\files/filename.exe&CALL :splitme
SET download=https://www.someone other.com\some files/filename 1.exe&CALL :splitme
SET download=http://www.someone.com/download/files/filename.exe&CALL :splitme
SET download=http://www.someone other.com/some files/filename 1.exe&CALL :splitme
SET download=http:\\www.someone.com\download\files\filename.exe&CALL :splitme
SET download=http:\\www.someone other.com\some files\filename 1.exe&CALL :splitme
SET download=http:\\www.someone.com/download\files/filename.exe&CALL :splitme
SET download=http://www.someone other.com\some files/filename 1.exe&CALL :splitme
SET download=//www.someone.com/download/files/filename.exe&CALL :splitme
SET download=//www.someone other.com/some files/filename 1.exe&CALL :splitme
SET download=\\www.someone.com\download\files\filename.exe&CALL :splitme
SET download=\\www.someone other.com\some files\filename 1.exe&CALL :splitme
SET download=\\www.someone.com/download\files/filename.exe&CALL :splitme
SET download=//www.someone other.com\some files/filename 1.exe&CALL :splitme
GOTO :eof

:splitme
IF NOT "%download%"=="%download:*:=%" SET "download=%download:*:=%"
FOR /f "tokens=1*delims=\/" %%i IN ("%download%") DO (
SET domain=%%i&SET file=%%~nxj&SET lop=//%%i&SET "pol=%%~nxj"
)
:lop
SET download=%download:~1%&set lop=%lop:~0,-1%&IF DEFINED lop GOTO lop
:pol
SET download=%download:~0,-1%&set pol=%pol:~0,-1%&IF DEFINED pol GOTO pol
ECHO + "%domain%" + "%download%" + "%file%"
GOTO :eof
```

Produces:

- "www.someone.com" + "/download/files/" + "filename.exe"
- "www.someone other.com" + "/some files/" + "filename 1.exe"
- "www.someone.com" + "\download\files\" + "filename.exe"
- "www.someone other.com" + "\some files\" + "filename 1.exe"
- "www.someone.com" + "/download\files/" + "filename.exe"
- "www.someone other.com" + "\some files/" + "filename 1.exe"
- "www.someone.com" + "/download/files/" + "filename.exe"
- "www.someone other.com" + "/some files/" + "filename 1.exe"
- "www.someone.com" + "\download\files\" + "filename.exe"
- "www.someone other.com" + "\some files\" + "filename 1.exe"
- "www.someone.com" + "/download\files/" + "filename.exe"
- "www.someone other.com" + "\some files/" + "filename 1.exe"
- "www.someone.com" + "/download/files/" + "filename.exe"
- "www.someone other.com" + "/some files/" + "filename 1.exe"
- "www.someone.com" + "\download\files\" + "filename.exe"
- "www.someone other.com" + "\some files\" + "filename 1.exe"
- "www.someone.com" + "/download\files/" + "filename.exe"
- "www.someone other.com" + "\some files/" + "filename 1.exe"

Explanation is trivial.

Comment: In the second last line, is the first `+` needed?

Comment: @user2033427 No, it's just there as a marker. Using markdown, it gets transformed to a bullet-point. I hadn't considered that, but it's a pleasing effect so I didn't bother changing it.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Echo OFF

FOR /F "Usebackq Tokens=*" %%@ IN ("MyURLs.txt") DO (

    Call :CorrectURL  "%%@"
    Call :GetBase "%%URL%%"
    Call :GetFile "%%URL%%"
    Call Echo [+] Base: %%Base%%    File: %%File%%
)

Pause&Exit

:CorrectURL
(Set "URL=%~1" & Call Set "URL=%%URL:\=/%%" & Call Set "URL=%%URL:http://=%%") & (Goto:EOF)
:GetBase
(FOR /F "Tokens=1,* Delims=/" %%B IN ('Echo %~1') DO (Set "Base=%%B")) & (Goto:EOF)
:GetFile
(Set "File=%~nx1") & (Goto:EOF)
```

First sub :**CorrectURL** replaces the backslashes for slashes, then secure deletes the "**http://**" string from the url.

Second sub :**GetBase** uses the slash as delimitter to split the string and get only the first token wich is the base url.

Third sub :**GetFile** treats the URL as a path so we can get the filename easy using the special var modifiers as you will see.

**Output**:

```
[+] Base: www.someone.com       File: filename1.exe
[+] Base: www.someone other.com File: filename 2.exe
[+] Base: www.someone.com       File: filename3.exe
[+] Base: www.someone other.com File: filename 4.exe
[+] Base: www.someone.com       File: filename5.exe
[+] Base: www.someone other.com File: filename 6.exe
```

If that is not the output that you desired just tell me to do changes in the code.

Answer (score 0):

This works here if the URLs are in File.txt

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /f "delims=" %%a in (file.txt) do (
set "var=%%~dpa"
set "var=!var:%cd%\=!"
set "var=!var:\=/!"
set "var=!var:/=/!"
echo "!var!" "%%~nxa"
)
pause



::file.txt
http://www.someone.com/download/files/filename1.exe
http://www.someone other.com/some files/filename 2.exe
http:\\www.someone.com\download\files\filename3.exe
http:\\www.someone other.com\some files\filename 4.exe
http:\\www.someone.com/download\files/filename5.exe
http://www.someone other.com\some files/filename 6.exe
www.someone.com/download/files/filename7.exe
www.someone other.com/some files/filename 8.exe
www.someone.com\download\files\filename9.exe
www.someone other.com\some files\filename A.exe
www.someone.com/download\files/filenameB.exe
www.someone other.com\some files/filename C.exe
```

Comment: It worketh not for me. First line for instance generates `"http:/www.someone.com/download/files/" "filename1.exe"` but I believe the desired result is `"www.someone.com" "filename1.exe"`. If I run it from the root of my RAMDRIVE (U:\) then the result from line 1 is `"U:/http:/www.someone.com/download/files/" "filename1.exe"` (W7HP)

Comment: I confirm that running from the root directory causes it to fail.  Any other folder is fine.  Your other point will have to be confirmed by the OP - I read it as the entire string.

Answer (score 0):

thank you all for your answers. But i want to split DOWNLOAD-URLs that are saved in variables.
And i forgot to say that i also want to work the script on FTP adresses.
But with the help of your answers and some further reaerch on the web i have found my own solution.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
mode con:cols=120 lines=32 && color 3E
title Example for splitting Download-URL into URL and Filename
cls

set _BASEURL=ftp://ftp.rarlab.com/rar/
set _WRx32=http://www.rarlab.com/rar/wrar v4.20.exe
set _WRx64=http:\/www.rarlab.com\rar files/winrar-x64-420.exe
set _WRLNG=rarlng.rar

:SPLIT
set COUNT=0
echo:_BASEURL = %_BASEURL%
echo:_WRx32   = %_WRx32%
echo:_WRx64   = %_WRx64%
echo:_WRLNG   = %_WRLNG%
echo:_____________________________________________________________________________

For %%A in ("%_BASEURL%", "%_WRx32%", "%_WRx64%", "%_WRLNG%") do (
 set Folder=
 set Name=
 set /A COUNT+=1
 if not %%~xA.==. (
  set "_vartmp=%%~A" ) else (
  set "_vartmp=%%~A\NO_FILE.EXT" )
 for %%B in ("Z:\!_vartmp!") do set "FILE!COUNT!=%%~nxB"
 for %%B in ("Z:\!_vartmp!") do set "_VAR=%%~dpB"
 set "_VAR=!_VAR:Z:\=!"
 if not $!_VAR!==$ (
  set "_VAR=!_VAR::\=:\\!"
  set "URL!COUNT!=!_VAR:~0,-1!" ) else (
  set "URL!COUNT!=NO_URL" )
)

set _BASEURL=%URL1%

set COUNT=0
:LOOPOUT
 set /A COUNT+=1
 if not defined URL%COUNT% exit /b 1
 if !URL%COUNT%!==NO_URL set "URL!COUNT!=%_BASEURL%"
 echo URL%COUNT%: !URL%COUNT%!\         --- FILE%COUNT%: !FILE%COUNT%!
goto LOOPOUT

SETLOCAL DisableDelayedExpansion
goto :EOF
```

First i save the Download-URLs into variables, then i print them out. Now i split the Link into
URL and filename. Then i save the URLs and filenames to dynamic variables (URL + consecutive numbering
and FILE + same consecutive numbering). As you can see there is no URL for the variable "_WRLNG", so the string "NO_URL" is saved instead of a url. And the link in variable "_BASEURL" doesn't have a filename, so the string "DUMMY.EXT" is saved instead. This must be done to have no empty/missing
URL+Nr/FILE+Nr variables and to get a correct 1:1 correlation.

The splitting is done by first adding a (virtual) drive letter ("Z:\") and later removing it to/from the Download-URL thus the 'Parameter Extensions' can be used. With "~dp" the command processor changes
all slashes to backslashes - but it also removes douple slashes/backslashes so the second backslash 
after "http:\" or "ftp:\" must be added again (by replacing ":\" with ":\"

Now the URL, that was saved in *URL1*, is assigned to the variable "_BASEURL" (any other URL can be
used - it's only an example because i read the variables from an INI file and use this script also for
correcting the notation of _BASEURL, if the user uses slashes instead backslashes.) The variable
"_BBASEURL" is used (here only for the output) where just a filename is saved witout a url.

In the line

echo URL%COUNT%: !URL%COUNT%!\      --- FILE%COUNT%: !FILE%COUNT%!

there are 1 space and 2 tabulators between "..\" and "---...". To insert the TABs i used
ALT+009 (on the numpad) in Windows Notepad (aa last step before saving). Doing this the
output should be seen as tab separated list.

i hope the explanation is halfway understandable.